# Running python from notepad in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, python-import

I am trying to run a python program

> import random
>   random.random()

Written in notepad in two different lines,I want to run it in cmd.how to do it?

Comment: That code won't print any output.

Comment: That's fine but it is showing module not callable error

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the program with a `.py` extention. For example: `hello.py`
2. Then run it with `python <script_name>.py`. For example: `python hello.py`

Comment: I did it but it is showing errors like: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: @DikeshKumar Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python3.5...does it vary with version

Comment: @DikeshKumar Are you using random.random() or just random() ? Just using random() will show the error that you mentioned above. Be sure to use `import random`  `print(random.random())`

Comment: @DikeshKumar No errors, neither with 2.7 nor with 3.5, executing a copy of the code you posted. IS the code that you saved into `hello.py` DIFFERENT from the code you posted?

Comment: I am using random.random()

Comment: Do you have some other file saved with the name random??

Comment: Hey guys Got the error.My file name was "random.py" and Was in the same directory as the cmd. Thanks for the help